# Should the same code the compiler uses be used in production code?

Tags: c#

I was reading this recent post by Jon Skeet: [How can I enumerate thee? Let me count the ways...](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/09/30/how-can-i-enumerate-thee-let-me-count-the-ways.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+JonSkeetCodingBlog+%28Jon+Skeet%27s+Coding+Blog%29). It is about investigating what code compiles into. In this case, he examines

```
foreach (char ch in text) 
{ 
 // Body here 
}
```

The final example he uses (for the case when text is of type `string`), he shows that the compiler converts the foreach loop into a while loop like this:

```
int index = 0; 
while (index < text.Length) 
{ 
 char ch = text[index]; 
 index++; 
 // Body here 
}
```

In this case, it may not be much of an effort to convert from the foreach loop to a while loop (or even necessary to make that conversion), but in a more general sense, should I be writing my code to be more similar to compiled code?

Comment: `should I be writing my code to be more similar to compiled code?` If that were true, no one would use Linq.

Comment: @L.B - haha, okay, so then just trust the compiler will do its magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are better off concentrating on writing readable, maintainable code and leaving the translation to the compiler.

If - with compiler improvements - the loop would better be rewritten/compiled in another way, you've actually made the job harder for the compiler to understand what you're trying to do, and may prevent it from translating the loop to the optimal instructions for the platform.

Answer (score 3):

No - what the compiler produces shouldn't be what you base your coding style on.

You should optimize for readability first - if you do see problems with performance, then, and only after profiling should you try to optimize.

Comment: I agree, writing for readability should be a very high priority. This was part of what lead me to ask this question, because I like using code which is more readable than what the compiler produces but was curious if there was a performance/efficiency difference.

Comment: @TravisJ - Don't forget that what the C# compiler produces is IL. This then gets transformed by the jitter to native code - would you want to write C# to emulate that?

Comment: Certainly not :) That would defeat the purpose of writing in a high level language. If that were the case everything would be done in `.asm`.

Comment: @TravisJ - Exactly... that's why you should keep to clean C# and not try to emulate the reverse engineered C# that was produced from the IL ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, the point of high level languages is to simplify programming.  The compiler will act as it should but there isn't a point in replicating it's behavior when the end result will be the same. Use the powerful features of the language instead.

Answer (score 2):

Figuring out how to transform C# code into something that can be represented in CIL is the compiler's job. As you've already seen, it does a good job at that. Do you trust yourself to do that job better? If so, sure, go ahead, but for the vast majority of programmers, myself and probably yourself included, that trust would be misplaced.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should use the shorthand ways that the compiler allows you.

It's not only less to write, it's also less code where there can be errors. If you take the example; it's hard to do a mistake in the `foreach`, but if you convert it to a `while` there are several small mistakes that you can do that keeps it from working, like for example forgetting the `index++`.

The shorthands in the compiler is there so that you can do the right thing with little effort. For example the shorthand for properties:

```
public int Value { get; set; }
```

This will be expanded to a member variable and a getter and setter that uses it (although the variable name is secret):

```
private int _value;
public int Value {
  get {
    return _value;
  }
  set {
    _value = value;
  }
}
```

Before that shorthand was added to the compiler, you were tempted to use a public member variable instead, just because it was a lot less to type:

```
public int Value;
```

Now you can have the cace and eat it. :) With just a few more characters you have a full fledged property without having to write the implementation yourself.

Comment: Nice example with the `private` variable. In c++ that is pretty standard, but it is very nice in c# to shorthand a public getter setter in one line.